# elasticsearch sort not working with partial_fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this kind of sort:

```
"sort": [
    {
        "_script": {
            "script": "return doc.score*10 + doc['field2'].value",
            "type": "number",
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
]
```

partial fields:

```
"filter": {
        "partial_fields": {
            "fields": {
                "exclude": [
                    "field5*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is that sort does not work if partial_fields is set.. is there a reason for this ? or how do I have to remove partial_fields in order to get sort working ?

here's the whole query:

```
{
"size": 10,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "name_en": {
                                "query": "testing",
                                "operator": "or",
                                "boost": 20
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "_type": "test"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "partial_fields": {
            "fields": {
                "exclude": [
                    "field2*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"sort": [
    {
        "_script": {
            "script": "return doc.score*1000 + doc['field2'].value",
            "type": "number",
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for partial fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html#partial), I do not see the usage as being nested under a `filter` node in the JSON request. I think this could be your issue, try moving the `partial_fields` section up to the same level as `sort` like the following:

```
{
"size": 10,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "name_en": {
                                "query": "testing",
                                "operator": "or",
                                "boost": 20
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "_type": "test"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }    
},
"partial_fields": {
       "fields": {
           "exclude": [
               "field2*"
           ]
       }
},
"sort": [
    {
        "_script": {
            "script": "return doc.score*1000 + doc['field2'].value",
            "type": "number",
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
]
}
```